# Why activityIndicator doesn't appear fast when I push the button

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to put an activityIdicator on my miew. The problem is that it works just before passing to other view, not suddenly when I push the button which means : I push the button, I wait a lot of time, and finally activityIndicator appear just before passing to other view so in a short time. I used a thread but the result is same. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)pressCars{
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
//...lots of computation...
[actIndicator stopAnimating];}`
- (void) threadStartAnimating {
[actIndicator startAnimating];
statusText.hidden=NO;
```

}

(IBAction) pressCars is linked with the putton I press, and also that button create the segue of the other view.
The other view I pass with the same button is a tableView which get plist data from web. but it loads fast, without spending time.
What can be the problem?
Thanks.